# "unable to resolve class GradleException @ line 11, column 15. "error is showing when i tried to resolve one or more plugins require a higher

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle, build.gradle

"unable to resolve class GradleException  @ line 11, column 15." error is showing
when i tried to resolve the error "one or more plugins require a higher android sdk version".

[image: the code]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the new keyword before the GradleException